# Removing Capital Letters between brackets on google sheets

Tags: google-sheets

on google sheets I am trying to remove some capital letters that exist between brackets using regexreplace

```
=arrayformula(regexreplace(regexreplace(A2:A,"\(.+?\)\ Ltd$| $| LTD$","")," $| LTD$",))
```

the only part remaining is where it could be random company (PTY) and I need to remove the space before the (PTY) and the (PTY).

any ideas?

Comment: It would be easier for us to test your formula and provide solution if you can provide sample data with the desired output.

Comment: share a copy of your sheet with example of desired result

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1sLg58u4E2zyTRR1szp8PWMU54MpLNjXjPg6GV-l26-U/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this formula:

```
=arrayformula(regexreplace(A2:A,"\s?\(.+\) (Ltd|LTD)$",""))
```

**Output:**

[image]

### Reference:

- [Regex capturing group](https://www.regular-expressions.info/refcapture.html)

Comment: much appreciated